# Import txt file data into datagridview c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to import data into my datagridview. The code I have so far is:

```
private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(DATA_FILE_NAME))
       fileIn = File.OpenText(DATA_FILE_NAME);
    else
    {
       MessageBox.Show(DATA_FILE_NAME + " does not exist", "Abort Execution", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
       Application.Exit();
    }
    if (listCountTextBox.ReadInt(out index))
        for (int i = 1; i <= index; i++)
          idList.Add(Int32.Parse(fileIn.ReadLine())); <----- Error here
        fileIn.Close();
        DisplayIDList(displayDGV);
}
```

The format of the data in the text file looks like this: "000-0000" and there are 1,240,000 values. The error says: Input string was not in a correct format.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank You!

Comment: it is not possible to convert a string like 000-0000 to an integer - what would you accomplish by convert the value?

Comment: if the data all has the same format you do not need to use `int32.Parse` just add the line to the `idList` which at this point is a String.. if you are going to store the data in a table the datatype would be `varchar` or `nvarchar`

Comment: also why close the application when all you have to do is replace this line in your code `Application.Exit();` with `return` it will break out of the void method..

Comment: Okay. Makes sense. I'm still new to c#, So I don't need `int32.Parse`. So do I just put `idList.Add(fileIn.ReadLine())` not sure if I understand what the syntax should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others responds is not posible to convert "000-0000" to int, thats the error.

Would work if you change:

```
idList.Add(Int32.Parse(fileIn.ReadLine().Replace("-","")));
//idList.Add(Int32.Parse(fileIn.ReadLine())); <----- Error here
```